# What's the meaning of the two scarves during the riot in Straight Outta Compton?

Tags: analysis, straight-outta-compton

Around 3/4 in the movie Straight Outta Compton during the riots, two people are holding two scarves, one red and one blue, knit together and walking towards the police.

Like so:

[image]

Closeup:

[image]

What's the meaning of this and/or what does it symbolise?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That scene depicts the [L.A. Riots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1992_Los_Angeles_riots) (related to the four police officers involved with the beating of [Rodney King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodney_King) being found not guilty).

Many gang members would wear colors (often in the form of bandanas) to show their affiliation (Red for Bloods, Blue for Crips). The day before the riots broke out, the Bloods and the Crips declared a truce ([called the Watts Truce](http://www.scpr.org/news/2012/04/28/32221/forget-la-riots-1992-gang-truce-was-big-news/)) so the tied red and blue bandanas are most likely to illustrate the joining together between the gangs to rebel against the L.A. police force.

Answer (score -4):

The Watts truce is depicted I'll make this short and simple the bloods and crips were initialized as a group of men and women who protected their neighborhoods from the racist police back then if you do some research on the two gangs it will explain much more clearer why the two bandanas are tied together being held in front of the police officers

Comment: Thank you for assisting the community. Ideas for framing an answer may include describing your sources along with a synopsis of what they said, and/or adding links to the resources and visuals you’ve found. I hope you enjoy participating.

Comment: That's why the OP asked the question...when answering questions on this site, it's best to post well researched information in _your_ answer.